# Dynamically revalidate nested array in formik

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, yup

This is the validation schema im using. i want to validate the prices of modifiers but the error doesnt show . below is my validation schema and code

```
  const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  Name: yup.string().required(' Name is Required').min(3),
  'Arabic Name': yup.string().required('Arabic Name is Required'),
  type: yup.string().required('Type is required'),
  modifiers: yup.array().when('type', {
    is: (type: string) => type === 'Service',
    then: () =>
      yup
        .array()
        .of(
          yup.object().shape({
            name: yup.string().required('Name is Required'),
            price: yup.number().min(0).required('Price is Required').default(0),
          }),
        )
        .required('Modifiers are Required') as any,
    otherwise: () => yup.array().notRequired() as any, // Define validation for other cases if needed
  }),
  price: yup
    .number()
    .when('type', ([type], schema) =>
      type == 'Product'
        ? schema.required('Price is Required')
        : schema.notRequired(),
    ),
});
```

The code is below

```
<FieldArray
      name="modifiers"
      validateOnChange={true}
      key={Math.random() * 10000}
    >
      {(arrayHelpers) =>
        formikObj.values.modifiers?.map((modifier, index) => {
          console.log(formikObj.values.modifiers[index]);
          return (
            <div
              key={index}
              className="w-full flex items-center justify-evenly md:w-2/5"
            >
              <label>{modifier.name}</label>
              <Field
                type="number"
                name={`modifiers.${index}.price`}
                placeholder="Price"
                className="w-4/5 bg-white rounded-lg border-[1.5px] border-stroke bg-transparent py-3 px-5 font-medium outline-none transition focus:border-primary active:border-primary disabled:cursor-default disabled:bg-whiter dark:border-form-strokedark dark:bg-form-input dark:focus:border-primary"
              />
              <ErrorMessage
                name={`modifiers.${index}.price`}
                component="div"
                className="text-danger"
              />
            </div>
          );
        })
      }
    </FieldArray>
```

the problem is that when type is service and im adding modifiers, when i leave the price field empty i dont get any error and the form is submitted succesfully.